# How do I update a ListView in an Android app for all users without updating the whole app?

Tags: android, sqlite, listview, rss

as an admin of my app, I would like to be able to add and delete ListItem without updating the whole thing.

Also, I would like the changes to be effective directly in every single copy of the app.

I thought about SQLite, RSS, but I'm not sure in which way I have to continue. As I'm relatively new to Android programming, I dont know much but maybe there's a simplest way to do that.

Thanks in advance

Comment: what is the data source of your ListView?

Comment: Text only, if that is what you meant.

Comment: You have the right idea. You will need to have the app pull its data from an external source, such as a parse.com database or a web service that you create.  Otherwise the only way to update the list is to put out a new version of the app.  The right way to do it depends on your needs and skills.